# .NET WooCommerce Rest API: Adding products(items) to order

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am quite the beginner when it comes to programming but I am creating a POS for my WooCommerce website with the .net wrapper. So far everything that I want to do is going well except for one thing.

I am trying to create a new order and pass the products in but I don't know how to add multiple products through the parameters. This is my code:

```
  public static async Task Transaction(int[] productId)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: Check if product is in stock

            Dictionary<string,string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["payment_method"] = "cash";
            parameters["set_paid"] = "true";
            parameters["line_items"] = ??

            await wc.Order.Add(new Order(), new Dictionary<string, string>(parameters));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to add an array to this ["line_items"] parameter or if I even could/should do this.

In PHP it looks like this:

```
$data = [  
    'payment_method' => 'cash', 
    'set_paid' => true, 
    'line_items' => [
        [
           'product_id' => 93,
           'quantity' => 2
        ]
    ]
];
$woocommerce->post('orders', $data)
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone here can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a dictionary as your parameters, it seems the Order object has a property "line_items", which is of the object "List"

So try something like this:

```
public static async Task Transaction(int[] productId)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: Check if product is in stock

            Dictionary<string,string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["payment_method"] = "cash";
            parameters["set_paid"] = "true";
            parameters["line_items"] = ??
            var lineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>();
            lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem());
            await wc.Order.Add(new Order(){ line_items = lineItems }, parameters);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

IntelliSense should be able to help you from there :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot. I was using v3 of the API so I wasn't  able to get the OrderLineItem(). I had to switch to v2.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help you :)